# Map Kinect to Projector

Tags: software-development

For a project for school we had the idea to make a project where a projector is used to project an image on a flat surface (table in our example). The Kinect and Projector could be suspended or placed below a see through table See image.

[image]

We would like to capture the touch events made on the table by using the Microsoft Kinect.

The problem is that we will have to map the Kinect onto the Projector Image. So we know whether the user has actually clicked something or not.

We haven't decided on what programming language we will use. But `Java, C#, .NET, Javascript~JQUERY` would our goto languages.

Does anybody know any libraries that can map these two together?

Things we already tried:

- https://code.google.com/p/ubidisplays/ This is seemed like our best bet, but we could not get it working after calibration.
- http://www.touchlesstouch.com/ This one doesn't even find the Kinect.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) project.

- It is free, both Libre & FOSS.
- I would go for programming in [python](http://python.org), also free and very good for learning.
- Lots of other language bindings:

  - C Synchronous - Provides functions to get data instead of callbacks
  - Actionscript
  - C++
  - C#
  - Java JNI
  - Java JNA
  - Javascript
  - Common Lisp
  - GFreenect (GLib) - Use Freenect from GLib. Also provides GObject Introspection which means automatic bindings for many other languages (Python, Javascript, Vala)